# Update next span with specific class using jquery

Tags: jquery

As shown below, I'm trying to update the html of a span when a value is selected from a bootstrap dropdown menu. I am trying to update whatever the next span is after the dropdown menu with class "requestStatus".

I thought something like $(this).closest('.requestStatus').html('updated status'); should do the trick but no such luck.

Here's the relevant markup:

```
<div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="pull-right dropdown-menu btnUpdateRequestStatus" role="menu">
        <li><a href="...">In progress</a></li>
        <li><a href="...">Complete</a></li>
        <li><a href="...">Cancel</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    some text <span class="requestStatus">status goes here...</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the jquery:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnUpdateRequestStatus", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    url: $(e.target).attr('href'),
    success: function(response){ 
      $(e.target).closest('.requestStatus').html('updated status');
    },
    error: function(){
      ...
    }
  });
});
```

I know there's a lot of questions similar to this, but I have seemingly tried all of the suggestions but nothing seems to work (continually just get "undefined").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because those are not ancestor descendant elements

```
$(e.target).closest('.btn-group').nextAll('.requestStatus').html('updated status');
```

---

```js
$(document).on("click", ".btnUpdateRequestStatus", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $(e.target).closest('.btn-group').nextAll('.requestStatus').html('updated status');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="pull-right dropdown-menu btnUpdateRequestStatus" role="menu">
      <li><a href="...">In progress</a></li>
      <li><a href="...">Complete</a></li>
      <li><a href="...">Cancel</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  some text <span class="requestStatus">status goes here...</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems like the cleanest solution to me.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$(e.target).closest('.requestStatus').html('updated status');
```

to:

```
$(e.target).closest('div.btn-group').parent().find('span.requestStatus').html('updated status');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2gf9bewa/)**

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your answer works nicely although I have picked Arun's answer as my preferred option simply because it seems cleaner to me. Others' mileage may vary, however.